# Problems nesting modules in shiny and using renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I have to call a module within another module to display a dataset filter. So the construction of the filter is dynamic and is done within a renderUI.
The problem is that it doesn't show me the filter.

I have created a code that exemplifies my problem.
I have two modules:
inner and outer.
From outer and I call inner.
If the call is made from a renderUI of outer (filter3), the button is not displayed.
It must be a namespace (ns) problem but I can't figure out why.

```
innerUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  hidden( 
    actionButton(
      NS(id, "filter"),
      label = NULL,
      icon = icon("filter"),
      style = "margin-left: 0px;"
    )
  )
}

outerUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  wellPanel(
    innerUI(ns("inner1")),
    uiOutput(ns("list_dtf"))
  )
}
innerServer <- function(id,
                             data = reactive(NULL),
                             hide = FALSE,
                             hover_text = NULL) {
  
  # SERVER
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # NAMESPACE
    ns <- session$ns
 
        print("!hide") 
        if (!hide) {
          print(hide)
          shinyjs::show("filter")
          print('show("filter")')
          print(id)
          if(!is.null(hover_text)) {
            addTooltip(session = session,
                       id = ns("filter"),
                       title = hover_text)
          }
        } else {
          print("escondo el filter")
        }
    }
  )
}

outerServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns  <- session$ns
      innerResult1 <- innerServer("inner1", hover_text="prueba tooltip 1")
      innerResult3 <- innerServer( "inner3", hover_text="prueba tooltip 3")
      
      output$list_dtf <- renderUI({
       
        div(
          h2("1 OTRO FILTRO:"),
          innerUI(session$ns("inner3")),
          h2("2 OTRO FILTRO:")
        )
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage( 
            wellPanel(
                  titlePanel("Select of Data File"),
                  useShinyjs(),
                  outerUI ("select_data_file"),
                  innerUI("inner2")
                  )
            )

# server
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
  outerServer ("select_data_file")
  innerServer("inner2",hide = FALSE,hover_text="prueba tooltip2")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You assign the return values of each instance of `innerServer` to the same object in your main server. That’s not going to help. Maybe there are other issues as well, but that’s the first thing I spotted. And I’m not sure if shinyjs is namespace-aware. I suspect not.

Comment: yes, well, it was possible to change the variables. But that's not the problem
  innerResult1 <- innerServer("inner1", hover_text="test tooltip 1")
      innerResult3 <- innerServer( "inner3", hover_text="test tooltip 3")

The issue is in the inner3 that is invoked within a renderUI

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
innerUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  #hidden( 
    actionButton(
      ns("filter"),
      label = NULL,
      icon = icon("filter"),
      style = "margin-left: 0px;"
    )
  #)
}

innerServer <- function(id,
                        data = reactive(NULL),
                        hide = FALSE,
                        hover_text = NULL) {
  
  # SERVER
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # NAMESPACE
    ns <- session$ns
    
    print("!hide") 
    if (!hide) {
      print(hide)
      shinyjs::show("filter")
      print('show("filter")')
      print(id)
      if(!is.null(hover_text)) {
        addTooltip(session = session,
                   id = ns("filter"),
                   title = hover_text)
      }
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("filter")
      print("escondo el filter")
    }
  }
  )
}
```

Comment: That functionality cannot be removed. You have to hide the button or show the button on demand. With inner1 and inner2 it works correctly. What does not happen with inner3, where the namespace is lost when the UI is called from renderUI

Comment: It does hide/show on demand. If you want to hide, call as `innerServer("inner2",hide = TRUE,hover_text="prueba tooltip2")`